# Difficulty nailing the syntax for a PostgreSQL query to grab timeline of posts

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm new to PG and having trouble getting the syntax of this query right. I keep getting `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "post_reactions"`. I'm sure it's a dumb oversight.

I'm trying to build your typical posts list with:

1. all columns and all rows from the `posts` **table** where users.id = 'whatever'
2. all the post reactions from the `post_reactions` **table** where the posts.id = post_reactions.post_id
3. the reaction keywords ('happy', 'sad', etc.) from the `reactions` **table** where the reaction.id = post_reactions.reaction_id
4. the display_name from the `users` **table** associated with each post reaction by matching the post_reaction.user_id with users.id and returning the users.disaplay_name from the users table.

```
SELECT 
       post_reactions.post_id,
       post_reactions.reaction_id,
       post_reactions.user_id,
       posts.content,
       posts.content,
       posts.create_timestamp,
       posts.id,
       posts.image_url,
       posts.updated_at,
       reactions.id,
       reactions.keyword,
       users.display_name,
       users.id
FROM public.posts
         LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (users.id = post_reactions.user_id)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN post_reactions ON (posts.id = post_reactions.post_id)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN reactions ON (reactions.id = post_reactions.reaction_id)
WHERE users.id = 'foobar'
;
```

Answer (score 2):

The tables need to be included in the `FROM` clause before they can be referenced in the `ON`:

```
FROM public.posts LEFT JOIN
     post_reactions
     ON posts.id = post_reactions.post_id LEFT JOIN
     reactions
     ON reactions.id = post_reactions.reaction_id LEFT JOIN
     users
     ON users.id = post_reactions.user_id
```

I would also advise you to use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read:

```
FROM public.posts p LEFT JOIN
     post_reactions pr
     ON p.id = pr.post_id LEFT JOIN
     reactions r
     ON r.id = pr.reaction_id LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = pr.user_id
```

The aliases, though, have to be used throughout the query.